# Google maps api Javascript 3D map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I am working on a development in which I have implemented the google maps Javascript api. As far as working on the 2D map is all very clear and documented, but I would love to know if there is any option or possibility to transform the map into 3D view which allows me to see 3D buildings, change tilt in view ... etc. Is there such a possibility ?.

Comment: While an interesting question, as it is, it is not really a good question for Stack Overflow. Can you edit your question to show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

No, Google Maps API only gives access to the 2D maps as well as Streetview.

3D maps and Google Earth is only available in google apps or the maps.google.com solution.